# Is it possible to access kubernetes deployment file from a shell script?

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to login into kubernetes platform via Linux without using token.

I'm trying to develop one automation in which I need to update replica sets from a shell script so I'm struggling with accessing kubernetes deployment file from a random VM as using token is not the solution for login into kubernetes platform.
So can anyone please suggest if there is any way to login into kubernetes via Linux server without using token?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `token`?

Comment: Would need to get some more information @Prarthna

Answer (score -1):

There's not nearly enough info provided to give you a "working" solution.

But if you're on a VM and want to access your cluster, this is easily done by configuring the VM with kubeconfig (auth to the cluster) and installing kubectl.

We're of course going to assume there's network connectivity between your VM and the K8s api server.